# Any PHP framework implements ODATA protocol?

Tags: php, laravel, odata, breeze, jaydata

Is there any php framework that implements odata protocol, native or by extension?

I need to use [breezejs](http://www.breezejs.com/) on the client and I hope I don't have to implement all the server side work of odata by myself.

in case there is no such thing, is there any alternative to breezejs?

[jaydata](http://jaydata.org/) is not an alternative, because actually it also requires the server side to implement odata protocol, so they are too similar.

Rest services, (like restangular in angularjs) are also not an alternative (not to me at least). They provide only a portion of the services of breezejs or jaydata. E.g. they don't provide caching data, change tracking or complicated rich query options.

any ideas?

thank you

Comment: There is one for laravel:  https://github.com/Algo-Web/POData-Laravel

Comment: Also for pure PHP: https://github.com/saintsystems/odata-client-php and https://github.com/POData/POData

Answer (score 4):

Yes - there is an [OData Producer Library for PHP](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/interoperability/archive/2011/09/09/the-odata-producer-library-for-php-is-here.aspx) which is available on [github](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/odataphpprod).

That might be both more and less than you need.  A Breeze client basically needs three things from the server:

1. Metadata describing the object model (which may be [written by hand](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/metadata-by-hand)).  OData's metadata may be inadequate because it sometimes omits foreign keys.
2. An way to handle saving changes (I don't think the OData Producer for PHP implements this).
3. A way to respond to the queries that your application needs.

You don't necessarily need the a full OData implementation.  Look into [breeze.server.php](https://github.com/adrotec/breeze.server.php); it might be what you need.

EDIT - [breeze.server.php](https://github.com/adrotec/breeze.server.php) actually uses the [OData Producer Library](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/odataphpprod).

Comment: OData Producer Library for PHP currently only supports read requests. We've tried to enhence it by the write part but with no success. Now we ended up using nodejs + jaydataserver for the server part.

Comment: Yes, OData writes are painful to implement; even Microsoft has trouble implementing the spec.  Breeze doesn't use OData writes unless required; it uses a JSON save bundle by default.

Comment: BTW, Breeze has upcoming support for the Sequelize ORM on Nodejs, as well as a non-OData JSON query protocol.

Comment: From the Data Producer Library's Github repository : **The OData Producer supports all Read-Only operations specified in the Protocol version 2.0**. So if you want to consume Odata v4 and/or you need write access as well, you're pretty much screwed.